# Allocating 2d array (type char) to prepare memory for float calculation

Tags: c, function, for-loop, pointers

First I have to input size of 2d array (n and m), and position of professor and strictness of prof.
Then I have to scanf matrix.

My problem is that i have type char matrix but I need to cast matrix into float because I need float numbers.

```
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            scanf(" %c", &mat[i][j] );
        }
    }
    scanf(" %c", &dane);

    **pass(mat, n,m, prof, strictness);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


float **pass(char **mat, int n, int m, int prof, int strictness){




    mat=(float **)calloc(n, sizeof(float *));
    if(mat==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nWRONG");

    }
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        mat[i]=(float *)calloc(m, sizeof(float));
    }
    return mat;
}
```

Is this the right way to allocate memory and good start to continue?

Input:
4 4
2 30

Z N N Z

X X X Z

N N N Z

N N N Z

Output

0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00

29.67   0.00  96.75   0.00

0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00

0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00

Comment: This is only a part of code, I asked is this a good start and did I allocate memory good

Comment: The incomplete paste stuff in the beginning doesn't show the declaration of `mat`. _Why_ do you have a `char` matrix if you need a `float` matrix? No, there is no sensible way to cast or copy between them unless you are dealing with raw binary data.

Comment: char mat[MAXR][MAXS]={};

I have char matrix because I need to input letters, and then calculate distance for every X from Z and N

Comment: So start by parsing the input and convert whatever string you have into numbers, before doing anything else.

Comment: My problem is if i calloc memory every spot in 2d matrix will be 0 and i cannot do anything with that, should I first calculate distance and than calloc or ?

Comment: Um, a float is 4 byte and a char is 1 byte. How are you going to cast its pointer? Why don't you try using scanf to scan for float? Or is it strictly have to be char?

Comment: First I have to allocate memory for char input, then i have results calculated in that float/double function put into another float function (i also have to allocate memory for output of first function)

Answer (score 0):

For this answer, I do not know what you are going to the with the float **. Nonetheless, I just show you how to allocate and convert char into it. Whether if the char value should be signed or unsigned that is up to you.

For allocating memory. There are two methods. The easy one is that you can just do two calls to malloc. Allocating a space for the pointer to pointer of float. Then allocating memory for the pointer to float. Basically the pointer to float is all the indexes of your 2D matrix, and mat is an array of pointer to them. When it come to 3D it different but for now it is like that.

The second method is a bit harder, but one you understand the first method it is easy. The second method is alloc enough memory for both the pointer to pointer and each float pointer in one malloc. The first byte address of that page of memory is the first index of the pointer to pointer. While that first address + the total size of the pointer to pointer is the beginning of the pointer to float.

It kind of hard to explain this in words but I hope the code help. After seeing the first method, it easy to understand the second method. I left the debug code in there so it easier for you to understand how they work.

## Method 1(2 malloc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float **pass(float **mat, int n, int m, int prof, int strictness);

int main(){
  int n, m, memIndex = 0;
  char dane;
  float ** mat;
  float * matIndexes;
  // Used unsigned char or signed char as approriate.
  unsigned char ctemp;

  puts("Enter n size:");
  scanf(" %d%*[^\n]", &n);

  puts("Enter m size:");
  scanf("%d%*[^\n]", &m);

  // n && m have to be at least 1
  if ( n < 1 || m < 1 ){
    puts("User input value is wrong.");
    return 1;
  }

  // Mat total size equal float pointer size times how many index.
  mat = (float **) malloc( sizeof(float*) * n );

  // Mat indexes total size equal float size multiply by how many index will be in the 2D matrix. size(2, 2) = [0][0], [0][1],[1][1] = 4 indexes. size(1, 1) = [0][0] = 1;
  matIndexes = (float *) malloc ( sizeof(float) * n * m );


  // mat && matIndexes can't be null.
  if ( mat == NULL || matIndexes == NULL ) {
    puts("Error when memory location.");
    return 1;
  }

  // Getting the char part
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    mat[i] = &matIndexes[memIndex];
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
      scanf(" %c", &ctemp );
      matIndexes[memIndex++] = ctemp;
    }
  }


  /* Print out the 2D Array. */
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
      printf("mat[%d][%d] = [%f] ", i,j,mat[i][j] );
    }
    puts("");
  }


  //scanf(" %c%*[^\n]", &dane);
  //**pass(mat, n,m, prof, strictness);
  /*
   * free mat[0] is also okay.
   */
  free(matIndexes);
  free(mat);

  puts("done");
  // system("pause");
  return 0;
}

float **pass(float **mat, int n, int m, int prof, int strictness){
    /* 
     * Your code goes here. 
     * I just left the return NULL so it
     * does not generate an error.
     */

    /*
    mat=(float **)calloc(n, sizeof(float *));
    if(mat==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nWRONG");

    }
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        mat[i]=(float *)calloc(m, sizeof(float));
    }
    return mat;
    */


    return NULL;
}
```

## Method 2 (1 malloc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdint.h>  // <- For uintptr_t

float **pass(float **mat, int n, int m, int prof, int strictness);
int main(){
  int n, m, memIndex = 0;
  char dane;
  float ** mat;
  float * matIndexes;
  void * mtemp;
  // Used unsigned char or signed char as approriate.
  unsigned char ctemp;

  puts("Enter n size:");
  scanf(" %d%*[^\n]", &n);

  puts("Enter m size:");
  scanf("%d%*[^\n]", &m);

  // n && m have to be at least 1
  if ( n < 1 || m < 1 ){
    puts("User input value is wrong.");
    return 1;
  }

  // Get enough spaces for both mat and matIndexes
  mtemp = malloc( (sizeof(float*) * n)
                 +(sizeof(float) * (n * m))
                );

  // if mtemp == NULL, fail memory allocation
  if ( mtemp == NULL ) {
    puts("Error when memory location.");
    return 1;
  }

  // Split up the space.
  mat = (float**)mtemp;
  matIndexes = (float *) ((char*)mtemp + n * sizeof(float*));

  // Getting the char part
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    mat[i] = &matIndexes[memIndex];
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
      scanf(" %c", &ctemp );
      matIndexes[memIndex++] = ctemp;
    }
  }

  /* Print out the 2D Array. */
  puts("");
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
      printf("mat[%d][%d] = [%f] ", i,j,mat[i][j] );
    }
    puts("\n");
  }

  /* Checking to see if the address allocate right matIndexes[0] should be mat + matSize */
  /* The correct cast to see the address is uintptr_t */
  puts("Checking to see address is right: ");
  printf("mat: %zu\n", (uintptr_t) mat);
  printf("matIndexes: %zu\n", (uintptr_t) matIndexes);



  //scanf(" %c%*[^\n]", &dane);
  //**pass(mat, n,m, prof, strictness);
  /*
   * free mat will free everything
   */

  free(mat);

  puts("\nDone!");
  // system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```